# File read write using MFC CFile

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm wondering why the below code not writing correct data to file. If I change the buffer size to some greater amout this code works fine.

For the below code, if I try to read a file less than 500 bytes it works good, but for a bigger file simply I have to increase the buffer. What I'm missing in the reading loop?

```
  const int iBuffSiz = 500;
  char chBuffer[iBuffSiz];
  memset(chBuffer, 0, sizeof(chBuffer));
    CFile file;
  CFile fileO;

  if(file.Open(XML_FILE_NAME, CFile::modeRead | CFile::typeBinary) == FALSE)
  {
    return;
  }

  if(fileO.Open(XML_FILE_NAME_O, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite | CFile::typeBinary) == FALSE)
  {
    return;
  }

  while(file.Read(chBuffer, iBuffSiz) > 0)
  {
    try{
      UINT iCount = strlen(chBuffer);
      fileO.Write(chBuffer, iCount);
    }
    catch (CFileException *exp)
    {
      TCHAR szCause[255];
      exp->GetErrorMessage(szCause, 255);
    }
  }

  //Closing file handle and socket after complete file send
  file.Close();
  fileO.Close();
```

Comment: You are opening the input file as _CFile::typeBinary_, but use _strlen()_ to get the length of whatever.

Comment: That's slightly misleading, @plaintext, as the `CFile::typeBinary` has nothing to do with the issues. The problem is rather that the OP has no guarantee, with or without that flag, that the buffer contents are a NUL-terminated string, which is required in order to use `strlen()`. Instead, check the documentation of CFile, I think it can tell you how many bytes it read. Lastly, two more hints: There are better ways to copy a file (search the web!) and catching and then completely ignoring exceptions is actively harmful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CFile::Read` doesn't null terminate the buffer, so `strlen` of buffer can be larger than the buffer, it runs in to buffer overflow. There is a way to get around this, but `strlen` still won't work with binary files, this time the buffer is cut too short. So it's better to use the value returned by `CFile::Read`

```
UINT iCount;
while( ( iCount = file.Read(chBuffer, iBuffSiz) ) > 0 )
{
   try
   {
      fileO.Write(chBuffer, iCount);
   }
   catch (CFileException *exp)
   {
      TCHAR szCause[255];
      exp->GetErrorMessage(szCause, 255);
   }
}
```

Comment: This works perfect and the reason is obvious. Thanks. Just one thing that I'm curious to know. If I change the while loop to 'while( iCount = file.Read(chBuffer, iBuffSiz)  > 0)' why it can't able to write the proper data into output file. >0 suppose to do the same work as above code, while loop will run till the value is true. Whats the issue here.

Comment: It needs another set of parenthesis to carry the result of `=` operator. I edited the answer with `> 0`. I am pretty sure CFile::Read doesn't return negative numbers but better be safe. Also it was confusing before.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Barmark that CFile::Read may return count more than buffer size specified

ONe more point I have is

*** You need to clear buffer after writing it to another file as it is pointing to string you already written to destination file , and because of this you may not get exact replica of file that is desired.

```
  while(file.Read(chBuffer, iBuffSiz-1) > 0)
  {
    try{
      UINT iCount = strlen(chBuffer);
      fileO.Write(chBuffer, iCount);
      memset(chBuffer, 0, sizeof(chBuffer));
    }
    catch (CFileException *exp)
    {
      TCHAR szCause[255];
      exp->GetErrorMessage(szCause, 255);
    }
  }
```

Comment: CFile::Read will return at maximum the number of bytes you specified as its second parameters, its the *strlen* on a not null terminated buffer that leads to undefined behaviour.
Also, you don't need to clear the buffer if you use the CFile::Read return value to determine how much buffer you can use and how much has to be discarded.